# Listens to the changes in the first woocomerce variation and applies the same selection to the second variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, cpu-word

I have 2 time the same variation on my Woo product page. I try to apply the changes of the first variation of a product lets say "Size: M" to the second variation on the same page.

I tried this code but no sucesss - i am still learning ....

Can you help with this ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {// Get the first variation elementvar firstVariation = $('.elementor-product-variable:eq(0)');
```

```
// Get the second variation elementvar secondVariation = $('.elementor-product-variable:eq(1)');
```

```
// Listen for changes in the first variationfirstVariation.on('change', '.variations select', function() {// Get the selected optionsvar selectedOptions = $(this).find('option:selected');
```

```
// Apply the same selection to the second variation
selectedOptions.each(function() {
  var attribute = $(this).parent().data('attribute_name');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  secondVariation.find('.variations select[data-attribute_name="' + attribute + '"]').val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

```
});});
```